# grant select on table1 (list of user)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

my goal is to grant select to all grantee´s of the three tables below.
Im not able to get the plsql script below running.

The following statesment works:
GRANT SELECT ON ZIP TO users_0;

I put that into a for each loop and got the following error:
"Table,View Or Sequence reference '' not allowed in
this context"

How can i reference to the table in this context?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE granting AS
BEGIN
    FOR users IN (SELECT DISTINCT GRANTEE FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS where TABLE_NAME = 'LAND' or TABLE_NAME = 'STREET' or TABLE_NAME = 'ZIP')
      LOOP
        BEGIN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON ''' || PLZORT || ''' TO ''' ||  users||'';
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON ''' || STREET || ''' TO ''' ||  users||'';
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON ''' || ZIP || ''' TO ''' ||  users||'';
        END;
      END LOOP;
END granting ;
```

Comment: Don't put quotes for table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to grant access to this 3 tables you could execute next:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE granting AS
BEGIN
    FOR users IN (SELECT DISTINCT GRANTEE FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS where TABLE_NAME = 'LAND' or TABLE_NAME = 'STREET' or TABLE_NAME = 'ZIP')
      LOOP
        BEGIN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON PLZORT TO ' ||  users.GRANTEE ;
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON STREET TO ' ||  users.GRANTEE ;
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON ZIP  TO ' ||  users.GRANTEE ;
        END;
      END LOOP;
END granting ;
```

But more likely you'd like to manage groups of users. For this you could prefer to create role. Something like that:

```
CREATE ROLE ROLE_ADDRES_RO;
```

Then you could grant access to this table to this role:

```
GRANT SELECT ON PLZORT TO ROLE_ADDRES_RO; 
GRANT SELECT ON STREET TO ROLE_ADDRES_RO; 
GRANT SELECT ON ZIP    TO ROLE_ADDRES_RO; 
GRANT SELECT ON LAND   TO ROLE_ADDRES_RO;
```

And then manually or by similar script grant this role to list of users:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
    FOR users IN (SELECT DISTINCT GRANTEE FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS where TABLE_NAME = 'LAND' or TABLE_NAME = 'STREET' or TABLE_NAME = 'ZIP')
      LOOP
        BEGIN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ROLE_ADDRES_RO TO ' ||  users.GRANTEE ;
        END;
      END LOOP;
END ;
```

In this case next updates of roles will be more transparent. And could be granted by only one database call

Comment: Thanks very much. Your and I3rutts answer solved worked for me. sadly the error message does not helped me very much (Oracle SQL Developer) to identify the quotation as a part of my failure.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below my example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE granting AS
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT DISTINCT GRANTEE, TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS where TABLE_NAME in ('LAND' , 'STREET' , 'ZIP'))
      LOOP
        BEGIN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || rec.TABLE_NAME || ' TO ' || rec.GRANTEE;
        END;
      END LOOP;
END granting ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much as well. I you and Michael Piankov helped me to solve my issue,